# Why does Scala support multi-name definitions with an expression that is evaluated for each?

Tags: scala

For most languages I wouldn't ask "why did they do X like this?" as it's generally opinion based.

For languages like C++ the usual answer is to quote some bit of some specification and all one can say is that someone probably thought long and hard before making a particular choice (but could have made a different choice).

Scala is different - often the answer is to point out that you can think of X in terms of some simpler structures Y and Z and so the formulation of X as it is makes sense when seen in this context.

So given that I'll ask why Scala allows a definitions that introduces multiple names and evaluates a given expression once for each name?

If you asked a Java programmer to guess what would happen here, they'd probably guess wrong:

```
var x, y, z = 3
```

I.e. they'd guess only `z` got assigned a value.

If you explained `val` and then told them the following was legal:

```
val x, y, z = 3
```

Then they'd probably guess more was afoot as clearly `x` and `y` must have values after this line as they cannot be assigned a different value later.

They might assume that `x` and `y` took a default values for their type, e.g. 0 for integers, but as there are no explicit types here that'd be a leap.

They might assume that it's handled as:

```
val z = 3
val x = z
val y = z
```

It doesn't really matter when the expression to the left of the `=` produces a primitive value or an immutable object. But the following might give them cause to wonder:

```
val x, y, z = new StringBuilder
```

Why would anyone want to introduce three names for the same `StringBuilder` instance?

And if you showed them the following they might, from the construction, guess that something odder was up before they even ran the code:

```
var i = 0

def f: Int = {
  i += 1
  println(i)
  i
}

val x, y, z = f
```

One eventually realizes that the expression that appears to only be associated with `z` is actually evaluated once for each name, i.e. the above is equivalent to:

```
val x = f
val y = f
val z = f
```

So is it even interesting to talk about what programmers who are used to another language *might* think?

Well most people come to a language like Scala from somewhere else so to a degree constructions that are likely to be confusing should be avoided unless there's a good reason for them.

At first glance this feature doesn't seem to offer much, it avoids you having to repeat yourself, but to add this piece of rather confusing syntactical sugar for such a small gain seems odd.

So is there some circumstance in which it brings real benefit? Or is there no real gain here but e.g. we maintain some kind of logical consistency with some broader pattern established elsewhere?

Comment: I'm guessing the close vote is due to the assumption that this is asking for what can only be an opinion based answer? But I'm guessing there may be a well considered logical reason for this language choice - as my opening and closing paragraphs state. Scala appears to be a language where something being a given way is more rarely an arbitrary choice than in many other languages.

Comment: It's quite interesting why you say `They might assume that it's handled as: val z = 3 val x = z val y = z` when it is expressed as `val x, y, z = 3`. If that was expressed as `val x=y=z=3` then probably such assumption would be natural :)
Also probably that piece of syntactic sugar was not added deliberately, but rather was included gratis by means already developed in compiler. So it could actually require more effort to disable such "feature".
By the way, I have never used such syntax so cannot really come up with a good example of usage.

Comment: Odersky himself actually uses this construction in his course "Functional Program Design in Scala". He develops a discrete event simulator for simulating digital circuits. These circuits involve a lot of wires and rather than declaring these individually he uses e.g. `val p, q, r = new Wire`. The `Wire` class involves mutable state so knowing exactly what's going on here is important. So it is a feature he uses rather than going "well it's more trouble to get rid of than to keep but as it's confusing let's pretend it doesn't exist" :)

Comment: Good point. In this example it just saves some characters to type :)

Comment: The shorthand is also for declarations: `val x, y, z: Int`. But not for defs, `def f, g : Int`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one case where this surprising feature is used: when defining a `scala.Enumeration`:

```scala
object Weekday extends scala.Enumeration {
  val Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday = Value
}
```

which calls `Value` (a `def` inherited from `Enumeration`) 5 times, once for each field of the enumeration. Effectively this allocates a new instance of `Enumeration#Value` for each field, which is obviously what you need for an enumeration to be useful.

Without this multi-assignment feature, you would have to write:

```scala
object Weekday extends scala.Enumeration {
  val Monday = Value
  val Tuesday = Value
  val Wednesday = Value
  val Thursday = Value
  val Friday = Value
}
```

I have never seen the multi-assignment feature used anywhere else but in an `Enumeration` declaration.

Whether or not this is good idea in terms of language design is a subjective question, and SO is not the right place to discuss it.

Comment: Well given where you are I guess you could pop around to Odersky and ask him :) Thanks for the enumeration example. As you say the perceived value of a given choice may be subjective but I was wondering if there was an interesting and specific reason for this choice. Scala doesn't look like a language where they just chuck in freebie syntactical "extras" without careful consideration (not that any language probably but does this but Scala even less than most).

Comment: Yes, I forgot about `Enumeration`.

Comment: The OP example https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M5/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/Imports.scala#L100

Answer (score 2):

You have basically answered your own question. The choice is between `val x, y, z = someComplexExpression` meaning

```
val z = someComplexExpression
val y = z
val x = z
```

or

```
val x = someComplexExpression
val y = someComplexExpression
val z = someComplexExpression
```

or not being allowed at all. The first is a bad choice for two reasons:

1. You mention the first: you don't generally need to give multiple names to the same instance.
2. If you choose the first, you have to duplicate the `someComplexExpression` every time you need the second, or to extract it to a method. If you choose the second, writing the first when you need it (despite point 1) is trivial:

   ```
   val z = someComplexExpression
   val x, y = z
   ```

Not allowing it would be possible. I don't think I've ever actually seen it used [before seeing your comment]. But removing it once it's allowed is a bad idea.

Obviously `var x, y, z = ...` needs to be consistent with this.

Comment: I agree that removing a feature once it's there is generally something that has to be considered very carefully. And I wasn't arguing for that. I was just looking for some justification as to why it was supported in the first place. As an aside the Scala creators seem to have been quite brave in removing features they've later regretted (some would say too brave, compared to other languages, leading to a lot of version-to-version incompatibility).

Comment: Considering the repeated-complex-expression argument, I'm uninclined to see it as enough in itself to justify this construction - as you point out extracting such an expression to a value or a method in order to reuse it should usually be easy.

Comment: The reasons for incompatibility between Scala versions are normally not because some features are removed, but because encoding of Scala features in terms of JVM bytecode changed, or because `@ScalaSignature` has to provide some extra data, etc.

Comment: Since you point out that Odersky himself uses it, it may just be that he considered it useful and non-confusing when he started working on Scala (or at least early enough) and other developers didn't consider it confusing.